# Update list after request react hooks

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, use-effect, use-state

I have a list of items stored in state. Upon form submission i add another item to the list and then save that as the new state. This newly added item has the status "pending." At the same time i send a post request and if the post request fails i want to update that particular items status to "error". The problem is, the state isn't updated by the time the request fails, and so i'm trying to update a state that isn't set. 
I am using react hooks, so one possibility is to call the request only after the state has updated:

```
useEffect = (()=>{
    function getRequest(URL, id, freq) {
       request happens here
    }
}),[state])
```

Previously, before putting the getRequest function in useEffect, it was called by another function in a child component.

My question consists of several parts: 
1) how do i get the parameters URL, id, freq into the useEffect function?
2) i don't want to run the getRequest function on first render, so how can i negate this?
3) is my general pattern of doing things here good (i'm sure it shouldn't be this difficult).

Comment: This is not how you use the `useState` function. Did you mean `useEffect`?

Comment: yep, thanks, just editied

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure you're updating an item that was already added to the `state`, then indeed the way to make this synchronously is to use `useEffect`.

However, I added an extra `state` variable, which represents the amount of items.
Then, whenever a new item is added, the API request will be executed and the (existing) item will be updated accordingly:

```js
const [itemsAmount, setItemsAmount] = setState(0);
const [items, setItems] = setState([]);

function addItem(itemData) {
  const newItem = {
    ...itemData,
    status: 'pending',
  }
  setItems([...items, newItem]);
  setItemsAmount(itemsAmount + 1);
};

useEffect(async () => {
  try {
    // Execute the API call
    const response = await apiCall();
    if (resposne && response.data) {
      // Add the successfully updated version of the item
      newItem.status = 'done';
      newItems.data = response.data;
      setItems([...items, newItem]);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // If the API call fails, add the "failed" version of the item
    newItem.status = 'failed';
    setItems([...items, newItem]);
  }
}, [itemsAmount]);
```

Comment: this was the order i was doing things, the thing is i can't update the item's status in the state because it isn't set.

Comment: @mdc29 Just realised what you were asking and updated my answer accordingly. Sorry for the misunderstanding